# Why is my vi editor going crazy?

Tags: vi

I created a file called package.json, and do the following command from cygwin on it :

```
vi package.json
```

This open up the editor like this: [image]

When I try to press 'I' in order to insert text, nothing happens except an i appears at the top of the file - or were the cursor is. When I scroll, more letters appear like this:[image]

Why cant I insert text in this case?

Also, when I get out of this editor, it saves a package.json.swap file - no idea why is does this either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that, for some reason, you are directly in the insert mode, because you press `i` and the letter i appears. Try to press `Esc` at the beginning, then things should be good. Also, when you are in the `insert` mode, arrows don't work. They just add some text just the way you explained. This proves that you are in the `insert` mode. The swap file is usually automatically delete upon exit. It can be left there if the process is killed for some reason. You can delete it safely (when vi is exited).

Comment: So  when I go into the command 'vi package.json' again, and try to press ESC as the first thing, nothing happens. Any other ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? If you type the word "hello", will it appear? If you press `Esc` after typing and then `:wq`, does it work?